command suggestions while typing for beginners
When typing the commands in any shell, can there be any kind of setting that can be enabled for beginners to type just an alphabet and it will suggest multiple commands that the beginner might be using? Just like in Google, when we start typing our search, it suggests multiple other things. Please suggest as I am also a beginner. Thank you.

Does this answer your question? Does Bash have similar features such as Fish's autosuggestions and highlighting?

Check zsh-autosuggestions

As far as I know, there is no such setting. However, most shell come with completion. Hit the TAB key to get a suggestion. Sometimes, you have to hit TAB twice. This is not exactly "as you type", but the nearest that is available. This mechanism is far from perfect. There are situations where this mechanism fails, depending on your shell and it's configuration.
For example, using bash, hit the q key, then hit the TAB key. As there are more than one possibility, the word is not completed immediately. Hit TAB a second time, the shell should produce all the possibilities. Now you have to help the completion mechanism a bit and add another letter. Say you enter u (your total input is thus qu so far). Hit TAB twice again and you should get a shorter list. If there are no commands that start with qu on your system, then the shell will not complete, obviously.

The fish shell offers something like this:

Install it onto whatever system it is that you are using, it should be in the repositories of most Linux distributions, and then run it with fish. Or make it your default shell with chsh.
